# How does this antenna match work?

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching

I had a matching technique described to me by a professional broadcast engineer. Here's the problem: you have a vertical antenna with a low resonant impedance<sup>1</sup>, let's say \$38\Omega\$, but you need a better match to a \$50\Omega\$ feedline.

Solution: put a coil between the base of the aerial and ground. Then, you feed off a tap in the coil:

[image: antenna matching schematic]

([image source: G3TSO on QSL.net](http://www.qsl.net/g3tso/Hombrew-Mobile%20Antennas.html))

How could this work? I can understand how adding a shunt inductor could improve the match if the antenna presents a capacitive load. But, why feed off a tap in the middle of the coil? If it's working as an autotransformer, wouldn't it be making the antenna impedance appear to be *less* to the feedline (the opposite of what we are trying to accomplish)? Also, if the antenna is already resonant, wouldn't the addition of shunt inductance make the match worse? Or is this why the feed is off a tap? Please help me understand how this works.

<sup>1: in my particular case, the impedance is even lower (I measure \$14\Omega\$) due to shortening of the antenna.</sup>

Comment: autotransformer?

Comment: @BrianDrummond that's my guess, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PhilFrost is it this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loading_coil you are talking about?

Comment: @Andyaka No. There is a loading coil in that picture (in the middle), but that's an irrelevant detail. I'm asking about the coil at the bottom. Also note important difference: the feedpoint is a tap on the coil. Also, a loading coil is used to make an antenna resonant at a frequency lower than its physical length, that is, to electrically lengthen the antenna. The matching coil here is used to match an *already resonant* antenna to a feedline of a different impedance.

Comment: @PhilFrost It's probably me being thick but i don't understand the question!

Comment: @Andyaka the question is simple: that coil with a tap somehow matches the antenna to the feedline. How's it work?

Comment: It's an autotransformer like Brian suggests. Ratio of turns squared changes impedance of centre tap to that at the antenna end.

Comment: @Andyaka wait...if it was an autotransformer, then wouldn't it have the effect of making the antenna impedance look *smaller* to the feedline? That's the opposite of what I've heard this should accomplish: it should take an antenna with an impedance *less than* 50 ohms, and match it to a 50 ohm feedline.

Comment: If the point marked TX is fed from a 50 ohm source then the top of the auto-transformer would be somewhat higher impedance in order to match the TX point to 50 ohms. On the other hand, if the cable length to point TX from an output stage was minimal, the AT is acting like a step-up transformer. Without knowing where the diagram came from or what you believe the diagram may be or should be showing I can't say any more.

Comment: @Andyaka I rewrote it to hopefully be more clear...make sense now?

Comment: Phil, is it possible that the broadcast engineer intended to say that the antenna connected to the tap (TX), and that the feed line was to the top of the autotransformer?

Comment: @Marla I'm certain this is what he intended to describe, but it's also possible he and the author of that image are wrong. A broadcast engineer is not an electrical engineer, and people on the internet have been known to be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see it working is if the lower impedance antenna (38 ohm) were connected to the "tap" of the auto transformer. A 38 ohm tap and a 50 ohm feedline means the tap is at 87% of the way up i.e. \$(0.87)^2 \times 50\Omega = \$ 37.8 ohms.

An 18 ohm tap is at 60% i.e. \$(0.60)^2 \times 50\Omega = \$ 18 ohms.

I can't see any other way round this other than the broadcast engineer got in a muddle or your ears need washing out LOL.

NB These calculations assume the auto transformer windings are 100% coupled to each other.

Comment: Interestingly, what you describe is in [another image adjacent to the one from the question](http://www.qsl.net/g3tso/images/Homebrew/Transformer%20Match.jpg). Though, the schematic shows a core and suggests a higher inductance, where maybe with the "autotransformer" solution there isn't enough inductance for it to be anything like an ideal transformer, or maybe parasitics are relevant. I think the text mentions an inductance on the order of \$1\mu H\$. Still, possible it's just plain wrong, and good to have a more experienced review.

Comment: @PhilFrost - it's still an auto transformer that new image is - think about the righthand coil just being placed below the 12.5 ohm tap and it should make sense dude. That 12.5 ohm tap is exactly at 50% hence it gives 0.25 x 50 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

Autotransformers can be used for both step-up and step-down impedance matching:

[image]

[image]

*[[Source]](http://m.electronicdesign.com/communications/back-basics-impedance-matching-part-1)*

Comment: "Here's the problem: you have a vertical antenna with a low *resonant* impedance". I'm not missing phase: it's specified as 0°. Also, don't you think the mutual inductance of the coils is somehow relevant?

Comment: @PhilFrost Yes, I do.  See my edit.